# In Salesforce, if there are multiple FLOWs active for the same object then does trigger fired only once or will it be fired for each FLOW

Tags: trigger, visual-workflow

In Salesforce, if there are multiple FLOWs active for the same object then does trigger fired only once or will it be fired for each FLOW (assuming each FLOW updates different fields)

Additional details : for e.g. for Account object,

- i have three record triggered FLOWs(say FLOW1,FlOW2 and FLOW3) and each of these FLOW updates different fields.
- Account object also have before and after apex trigger which performs some action.
- first Before and After trigger is fired, then FLOW1, FLOW2 and FLOW3 runs(order of FLOW is not an issue).

My question is after FLOW1 runs and updates a field does before and after trigger executes?

and then again after FLOW2 which updates another field, will before and after triggers fired?(and so on)

OR does before and after trigger is fired only once after FLOW1,2 and 3 runs.

I have checked debug logs how it executes and i am seeing both cases where sometimes trigger is fired after all 3 FLOWs runs and in some cases trigger is fired each time FLOW runs so i am bit confused.

Comment: Hi and welcome to SFSE. Please read [How to Ask](/help/how-to-ask) and perhaps take the [tour] to find out how best to ask your questions and what sort of detail you should include.

Comment: BTW, this question is ambiguous. When you ask "does trigger fired only once" do you mean "does an apex trigger get fired only once"? Note, too, that triggers handle various different phases for various actions (before and after phases against create, update, delete and other actions). The [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm) explains this reasonably well.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have updated the details with more specific question. Thanks for your replies

Comment: see step 13 and the Note in the doc linked by Phil W

Comment: Thanks cropredy!, my item is related to point 14 and more specifically if there are three FLOWs will before and after trigger too fired 3 times?

Answer (score 0):

If there are multiple flows active for the same object, the trigger will fire only once for each context (before-save or after-save). However, the order in which the flows run depends on the trigger order value that you assign to each flow. Flows with the same trigger order value run in alphabetical order based on their API name. Flows without trigger order values run next and in the order of their created dates.

For more information:

- https://forcepanda.wordpress.com/2021/12/15/flow-automation-strategy-one-flow-per-sobject-per-context-or-multiple-flows/
- https://www.salesforceben.com/how-many-flows-should-you-have-per-object/

Comment: It would be good to link to the [official documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_order_of_execution.htm).

Comment: Thanks @Tushar Jadav, the documention gives good information and helpful but does not answer my question :(. I have updated my question with more details. Can you pleae review and help?

Comment: Thanks Phil W, i had reviewed the documentation before. if you see point 14"Executes record-triggered flows that are configured to run after the record is saved" it does not say explicitly if Apex trigger will run or not for each record triggered FLOW.